# jQuery Hover issue in Firefox

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to fade in a new image on the hover state and replace the current png with "_over.png". It works well in Chrome and Safari, however it doesn't work in firefox.

Instead of looking for the _over.png in the same folder as my initial .png, it strips the url and doesn't add the _over. So firefox searches for "http:www.png" on the rollover, but the fade still happens.

This is my function:

```
$(function() {

$('img.fade').hover(function() {
  var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "_over.png";
   $(this)
      .animate({opacity:0},0)
      .attr('src',src)
      .stop()
      .animate({opacity:1},1000);
 }, 

function() {
  var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("_over", "");
  $(this)
    .animate({opacity:0},0)
    .attr('src',src)
    .stop()
    .animate({opacity:1},1000);
});
});
```

I'm new to jQuery and haven't found any solution to this online, so I'm at a total lost. It could just be an obvious stupid mistake. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this trying to add "_over"?

```
var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "_over.png"
```

The `match()` method returns match object, which may or may not `toString()` to something useful for you, which would explain inconsistency between browsers.

What you probably what is simply

```
var src = $(this).attr("src").replace(/\.png$/i, "_over.png");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That didn't work...it ended up breaking completely. However I think I figured it out. I was calling in jquery-1.5.js and masonry.js at the same time, which seem to be clashing in Firefox and IE....such a bummer cause they work so well together in Chrome. Thanks again!